# Call a definite parameter on button click

Tags: javascript, function, parameters

The advertisers provided the 2 custom scripts for tracking events on the page. One is for tracking the page visitors and the other is for tracking the button click.
The differences in provided scripts are just in a9.segmentName, but the second script should be fired only on button click. as I understand, I should combine these 2 together and just call the definite parameter (segment) on button click?

```
<script>
    var a9 = new Object();
    a9.clientName="SafetyDriven-Trucking-Safety-Council";
    a9.clientID=123456;
    a9.eventType="conversion";
    a9.segmentNumber=1;
    a9.segmentName="LandingPage";
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//a.tribalfusion.com/pixel/tags/SafetyDriven-Trucking-Safety-Council/768413/pixel.js"></script>
```

and

```
<script>
    var a9 = new Object();
    a9.clientName="SafetyDriven-Trucking-Safety-Council";
    a9.clientID=123456;
    a9.eventType="conversion";
    a9.segmentNumber=1;
    a9.segmentName="RegistrationSuccess";
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//a.tribalfusion.com/pixel/tags/SafetyDriven-Trucking-Safety-Council/768413/pixel.js"></script>
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: I'm asking how I can call a definite parameter on button click? I guess. But I'm also puzzled how to combine these two segmentNames in one function? Should it be an array with cases? and then depending on the action the definite case will be called?